The purpose of the public method that only calls private pure virtual function
While reading about C++17 library features, I found public methods that simply call private pure virtual methods. For example:

std::pmr::memory_resource::allocate

void* allocate( std::size_t bytes, std::size_t alignment = alignof(std::max_align_t) );

Allocates storage with a size of at least bytes bytes, aligned to the specified alignment.
Equivalent to return do_allocate(bytes, alignment);


std::pmr::memory_resource::do_allocate

virtual void* do_allocate( std::size_t bytes, std::size_t alignment ) = 0;

and

std::basic_streambuf<CharT,Traits>::pubsync, std::basic_streambuf<CharT,Traits>::sync

(1) int pubsync();
protected:
(2) virtual int sync();


Calls sync() of the most derived class


why such pattern is used?
I read What is the point of a private pure virtual function? and some articles about NVI idiom, but nothing explains the above cases that a method does nothing but calls private method and has no overloaded methods.

NVI idiom doesn't require to have not just a simple call to private method.

This article by Herb Sutter explains the reasoning.

The high level reason is separation of concerns.  Decoupling the public-facing API from the inheritance-facing API.

Also, a pragmatic reason (for larger programs), it is an affordance to make debugging significantly easier by having a good place to put a breakpoint.  Or for old school debugging, a good place to put a debug print statement.
